# Same ASP.NET virtual directory, different behavior, why?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, application-pool, isapi

I use C# to create a virtual directory and the default document in IIS is an .aspx file. I also created an application pool for this virtual directory. The application pool's property is “Integrated” for .NET 4.0.

On virtual machine A, the virtual directory can be visited in browser.
On virtual machine B, the virtual directory can’t be visited in browser.

I add this node in the web.config on VM B, the virtual directory can be visited too

```
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

But I’m confused that why VM A could be visited without adding the above node?  Both VM A and VM B are windows 8 and IIS7.

Can anyone offer me some help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is no differences in the web.config files between those machines. Not only web.config of your virtual directory (by the way, since you have app pool assigned it is `Application` not `Virtual Directory`) but also web.config of parent directories. There might be inherited configuration elements which are not compatible with application pool running in the `Integrated` mode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Tomek.But my application is not in the "wwwroot" folder, i put it in the "C\program files(x86)" directory, i checked the directory and didn't find any config file in its parent folder. I also checked the "wwwroot" folder and there are no config file in it either. There is only another application's folder, and in that application folder there is a web.config file. I found a <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
node in it. Will this config inherited by my application? thanks!

Comment: When it comes to configuration inheritance you have to look at the IIS hierarchy of applications (i.e. how you can see it in IIS Manager). Often there is main application mapped as a `Website` and under website you've got `Virtual Directories` and `Applications`